# How do I change cloud run project region 'us-west1' to 'asia-south1'

Tags: google-cloud-run, region

I have a Django project running with google cloud run in 'us-west1' region. I want to switch that region to 'asia-south1', How is that possible?

Project should run through 'asia-south1' region so that response time will get reduced. ( I don't need multi-region facility, as all my customers belongs to that region only)

I have seen such functionality in a compute engine at following link

[changing_the_default_region_or_zone](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/regions-zones/changing-default-zone-region#changing_the_default_region_or_zone)

But I am looking a solution for cloud run service.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Let's go back to basics.

When you deploy Cloud Run, you deploy a service to a region.
You can deploy the same service, with the same name in multiple regions as well.

What you need to do is re-deploy your service choosing the new region as your choice.

Comment: Thanks for the reply, You are saying that I should create a new service and deploy project on top of it. Could you elaborate it more?

Comment: You cannot `re-deploy` directly from an existing service but you can copy and create another service in different region. Difference here is that u r not moving, u r copying.